# how To reduce execution time of the following program

Tags: java, for-loop

I have a requirement, in which I have to scan certain files for the match of certain keywords. My keywords list size is around 40000 and all my files have approximately 4000 lines. Also the keyword should not be commented in the file, hence I have to take care of comments as well. The code what I have written to know the occurrence of the keyword is taking around 5 minutes for each file. I don't know what change I can make to reduce the execution time.
The code is as shown below.

```
for (File fl : files) {
        flag = false;
        content = FileUtils.readFileToString(fl);
        System.out.println(fl.getName());
        fileName = fl.getName();

        // Object Keywords scanning
        keywords = null;
        keywords = findKeywordType(fileName);
        if (keywords != null) {
            Boolean keywordCount = false;
            for (String[] key : keywords) {
                key[0] = key[1];
            }
            for (String[] key : keywords) {
                Boolean check = false;
                if (content.contains(key[0])) {
                    if (content.contains(key[3] + ".")) {
                        check = true;
                    }
                    if (check) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (content.contains(key[3])) {
                        keywordCount = FindOccurence(fl, key[0], key[3]);
                        if (keywordCount) {
                            System.out.println("Writing keywords");
                            objKwm = new ObjectKeywordMaster();
                            objKwm.setObjectName(key[0]);
                            objKwm.setObjectType(key[1]);
                            objKwm.setObjectOwner(key[2]);
                            objKwm.setDependentObjectName(key[3]);
                            objKwm.setDependentObjectType(key[4]);
                            objKwm.setDependentObjectOwner(key[5]);
                            objKw.getObjectKeywords().add(objKwm);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

FindOccurrence method code is

```
private static Boolean FindOccurence(File fl, String objectName, String keyword) throws IOException {
        int startComment = 0;
        int endComment = 0;
        Boolean objCheck = false;
        Boolean keyCheck = false;
        Boolean check = false;
        List line = FileUtils.readLines(fl);
        int fileLength = line.size();
        int objCount = 0;
        int keyCount = 0;
        loop:
        for (int j = 0; j < fileLength; j++) {
            if (line.get(j).toString().contains("/*")) {
                startComment = j;
            }
            if (line.get(j).toString().contains("*/")) {
                endComment = j;
            }
            if (line.get(j).toString().contains(objectName)) {
                objCheck = false;
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b" + objectName + "\\b");
                Matcher m = p.matcher(line.get(j).toString());
                while (m.find()) {
                    objCheck = true;
                    objCount++;
                }
                if (objCheck) {
                    if (line.get(j).toString().contains("#")) {
                        int objIndex = line.get(j).toString().indexOf(objectName);
                        int commentIndex = line.get(j).toString().indexOf("#");
                        if (objIndex > commentIndex) {
                            objCount--;
                        }

                    } else {
                        if (line.get(j).toString().contains("--")) {
                            int objIndex = line.get(j).toString().indexOf(objectName);
                            int commentIndex = line.get(j).toString()
                                    .indexOf("--");
                            if (objIndex > commentIndex) {
                                objCount--;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if ((j >= startComment && j <= endComment)||(j >= startComment && endComment==0)) {
                        objCount--;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (line.get(j).toString().contains(keyword)) {
                keyCheck = false;
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b" + keyword + "\\b");
                Matcher m = p.matcher(line.get(j).toString());
                while (m.find()) {
                    keyCheck = true;
                    keyCount++;
                }
                if (keyCheck) {
                    if (line.get(j).toString().contains("#")) {
                        int objIndex = line.get(j).toString().indexOf(keyword);
                        int commentIndex = line.get(j).toString().indexOf("#");
                        if (objIndex > commentIndex) {
                            keyCount--;
                        }

                    } else {
                        if (line.get(j).toString().contains("--")) {
                            int objIndex = line.get(j).toString().indexOf(keyword);
                            int commentIndex = line.get(j).toString()
                                    .indexOf("--");
                            if (objIndex > commentIndex) {
                                keyCount--;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if ((j >= startComment && j <= endComment)||(j >= startComment && endComment==0)) {
                        keyCount--;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(objCount > 0 && keyCount >0){
                check = true;
                break loop;
            } else
                check = false;
        }
        return check;
    }
}
```

I have two find occurence of two keywords present in the same list. Please suggest some ways so that I can reduce the execution time.

Comment: Is it possible to reduce your keywords list size? For example, does is contain case sensitive keywords (The, the, THE, ...)?

Comment: You should probably use a better algorithm. Your implementation is *very* naive. E.g. Some implementation of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho-Corasick_algorithm could speed up your program considerably.

Comment: these keywords are coming from database, i cannot reduce the size or ignore any of the keyword

Comment: Maybe reducing the disk IO would already help. For each keyword you read the file again into a list. Execute `List line = FileUtils.readLines(fl);` only once per file. You only told it's running 5 minutes and you want to run it in a shorter time. What is the goal you want to achieve and why? Then better proposals would be possible.

Comment: It is the requirement of my project, the files I am scanning are concurrent programs, functions view etc. By checking the occurrence of the set of keywords which depicts some objects, I have find out dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Before to start looking for any keyword, prepare the file content: remove the comments, ... .

2) Split file content in words.

3) Do not loop for each keyword: use a Set who stores all keywords.

Comment: I removed the comments as soon as I am reading the file as you suggested. And also the keyword array has 6 columns, So it gives each row as unique only. The time is reduced comparatively but still its not very fast. I just have 40k keywords, it should not take very long.

Comment: I do not understand the statemernts about keyword array columns. If you loop over all keywords for each file, you have a cost O(k*f), where "k" is number of keywords and "f" number of file. If you store keywords in a set, the cost is O(log(k)*f). For 40.000 keywords, that is around 2500 times faster.

Comment: My keyword array is a 2d array with 6 cloumns. So the combination of the values in each column make every row unique. If by using Set, you mean to have unique data,that wont help in this case because the data is already unique

Comment: Set is a generic type with the characteristics that, in the most usual implementations based on a data tree, has a search cost of O(log(n)).

Comment: How should I make a 2D set? I tried some ways but don't know the proper syntax.